# Unable to play audio recorded + record issues

Tags: android

My issue is that i cannot actually play a audio that recorded on the app. When i tapping on the play audio button, no audio sound.
Here's my JAVA code : please have a look.

Error I am getting is: stop called in an invalid state: 4 on mediarecorder.prepare();

I did remove any unnecessary parts:

code link :

```
mClick.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

             if (motionEvent.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                 startRecording();
                 mRecordState.setText("מקליט..");
                 new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                         secondsRemaining++;
                         String secondsRemaining_String = Integer.toString(secondsRemaining);
                         //Toast.makeText(soundSelectBasic.this,secondsRemaining_String,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                         //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                     }

                     public void onFinish() {
                         if(recordCounter==1&&secondsRemaining>=2){
                                stopRecording();

                             }
                     }

                 }.start();
             } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                 if (secondsRemaining>=2) {
                     recordCounter++;
                     stopRecording();

                 }
public void startRecording() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecordState.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);


    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");


} catch (IllegalStateException ioe) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");

}
Toast.makeText(soundSelectBasic.this,"ההקלטה החלה",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




}


private void stopRecording() {

    try {
        mediaRecorder.stop();

    } catch (IllegalStateException ioe) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "stop() failed");

    }
        mediaRecorder.release();
    mediaRecorder = null;

    mClick.setEnabled(false);
    mClick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    grayPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mRecord.setEnabled(false);
    mRecordState.setText("ההקלטה הסתיימה.");
    new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            displayConfirmDialog();            
        }

    }.start();}}`
```

Error:

```
09-04 17:58:55.644 2275-2275/com.commandofox.myapplication E/Record_log: prepare() failed
09-04 17:58:56.804 2275-2275/com.commandofox.myapplication E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 4
09-04 17:58:56.804 2275-2275/com.commandofox.myapplication E/Record_log: stop() failed
09-04 17:58:59.964 2275-2275/com.commandofox.myapplication E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code and tell us what the issue is exactly

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is the play button java link : https://pastebin.com/dnQQKsym

Answer (score 0):

Error invalid state: 4 (interrupted system call) is most likely:

- didn't add permisions to write data on external/internal storage in Manifest

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
- didn't add permision for mediarecorder to record in Manifest

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`
- error in the name, which I am not able to check

Comment: I did add those premission to my android menifest.

Comment: how about file name?

Comment: But i think that i haven't added write&read premmisions to Interal storage,( i did only to extrenal storage.) Could you tell me those premmisions, please?

Comment: there are no such permisions, though name/path is probably the reason of error. Could you paste your "mFileName"?

Comment: Hi, this is my file name as shown at the Java code:

Comment: mFileName= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording.3gp";